# Worst amount of tries it takes to guess the right number

Tags: algorithms

Let a random number R below X is to be guessed.

A wrong guess, G, which is higher than R can only be made once. If a wrong guess is made 2nd time, then you can't make any more guesses. (G>R)

A wrong guess, G, which is lower than R can be guessed any number of times. (G<R)

Is there any algorithm which can output the worst amount of tries it takes, T, to guess the correct value of R? (G=R)

Example:

X = 1 then T = 0

X = 2 then T = 1

X = 10 then T = 4

X = 23 then T = 7

Comment: FYI: This is essentially the "two egg problem". You can probably google that phrase to find more info.

Comment: Why R and not N? For R you fail for sure.